# What does the regular expression "(?i)" mean?

Tags: r, regex

Here is an example, for context...

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(col, "(?i)animal"))
```

And another one:

```
df1 <- df %>% filter(str_detect(col, "(?i)^([a-z]).*\\1$"))
```

Comment: It sets the “case insensitive” flag.